# How to setup chromedriver inside RobotFramework with chromedriver_binary

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Looking at https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/,

to set chromedriver_binary in python is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

How to do the same in robot framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the dependency by pip, add this command Before call `Open Browser`:

```
Evaluate    chromedriver_binary.add_chromedriver_to_path()     modules=chromedriver_binary
```

Then you can run `Open Browser`

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to provide the executable at the instantiation of the chromedriver. In Robot Framework `SeleniumLibrary` this is done using `executable_path` parameter. This then results in the following example:

```
Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe
Go To    http://cnn.com
```

Additionally when the download of the library fails, it would register as a test failed. In my view the test should not have started if the minimum requirements for running the test are not met. The download of the chromedriver is in my view one of those requirements.

In it's current form the version that `chromedriver_binary` is hard coded to 80.0.3987.16.0. It is recommended that you are able specifically target a version yourself when starting your scripts. For this reason I'd recommend making a configurable download for chrome driver, if you must.

Comment: Yeah, but for this you need to download the chromedriver previously.

If you install the python package chromedriver_binary, it downloads for you and setup the PATH automatically.

Also, the question here is to setup chromedriver with chromedriver_binary

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your comment.